# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' trying to convert python 2.7 to python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.6

i am working on a surveillance system. where i use openface, flask, python, opencv. When i run webapp.py in python 2.7 it works fine. but when I run in python 3.6 i am getting the errors. I resolve most of the errors but i stuck in this ( a byte-like object is required not 'str')
here is the code:

```
  def __init__(self):
        self.net = openface.TorchNeuralNet(args.networkModel, imgDim=args.imgDim,cuda=args.cuda)
        self.align = openface.AlignDlib(args.dlibFacePredictor)
        self.neuralNetLock = threading.Lock()
        self.predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(args.dlibFacePredictor)

        logger.info("Opening classifier.pkl to load existing known faces db")
        with open("generated-embeddings/classifier.pkl", 'r') as f: # le = labels, clf = classifier
            (self.le, self.clf) = pickle.load(f) # Loads labels and classifier SVM or GMM
```

and other part of the code is as:

```
 def reloadClassifier(self):
        with open("generated-embeddings/classifier.pkl", 'rb') as f: # Reloads character stream from pickle file
            (self.le, self.clf) = pickle.load(f, encoding= 'utf-8') # Loads labels and classifier SVM or GMM
        logger.info("reloadClassifier called")
        return True
```

and pickle.dump() places here:

```
  self.clf.fit(embeddings, labelsNum) #link embeddings to labels

        fName = "{}/classifier.pkl".format(workDir)
        logger.info("Saving classifier to '{}'".format(fName))
        with open(fName, 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump((self.le,  self.clf), f) # Creates character stream and writes to file to use for recognition
```

Comment: Please copy the text of the error instead of using an image.

Comment: File "/home/mave/hs/system/FaceRecogniser.py", line 90, in __init__
    (self.le, self.clf) = pickle.load(f) # Loads labels and classifier SVM or GMM
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: You can edit your question to add more details.

Comment: As is, it is unclear from the question what is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

When using `pickle` you should read the file as binary.

Just replace:

```
with open("generated-embeddings/classifier.pkl", 'r') as f:
```

with

```
with open("generated-embeddings/classifier.pkl", 'rb') as f:
```

and it should work.

Comment: i did but it is not working yet now i am getting the error. UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 372: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: @MrFahad In the same line?

Comment: @MrFahad It means that you did not do a standard `pickle.dump()` in the first place and your data does not have `ascii` encoding. Try using a different encoding when loading, e.g. `(self.le, self.clf) = pickle.load(f, encoding='utf8')` or some of the other [Python-supported encodings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings)